# Getting all contacts timestamp wise

Tags: android, timestamp, contacts, android-contentprovider

I have been trying to get all contacts of device sorted by the order they were added.
I am using following query:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_STATUS_TIMESTAMP };

    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_STATUS_TIMESTAMP);
```

It is not making any difference whether I am passing `null` or `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_STATUS_TIMESTAMP` in the sort order of the query

After inspection, the cursor has `null` in all timestamp columns. Is there a way to get this done or what I am doing wrong in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the timestamp for the status update for the contact. You are getting null probably because none of the contacts have status updates.

Because of how contacts are aggregated, i don't think there is a way to find out which contact was added first because a contact's ID can actually change and appear to be added later than it originally was. Why do you want to figure this information out?

Comment: @roberty- I want to show all contacts in 3 different lists depending upon a criteria. so I am adding all contacts to a a db first with flags as to which contact should come up in which list. now when application resumes it should check whether a new contact has been added or if so add it to db. anyway I got it done other way around but would still like to know whether how contacts'id change and what status means when talking about contacts

Comment: The status can be injected by your app into the People/Contacts app. By default, I believe it just grabs it from your GTalk status. There's two types of contacts, RawContacts and Contacts. Contacts are a collection of raw contacts. If you add a new Raw Contact, the system might go through re-aggregation and figure out if that newly added Raw Contact belongs to an existing Contact. This is so you don't have 3 entries for the same person with a gmail, twitter, and facebook account. During this process, Contact IDs might get changed.