# how can I get contacts order by date added or updated in android

Tags: android, date, android-contacts

Is it possible that how to get the order of the contacts when it is added or updated.
I search too much but did not find the useful clue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this out on Android Stack Exchange:

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5749/how-can-i-sort-contacts-by-date-added

Comment: Actually I want the original dates for adding or updating a contact. this link does not help in this way.

Comment: Because of how contacts are aggregated, i don't think there is a way to find out which contact was added first because a contact's ID can actually change and appear to be added later than it originally was. Why do you want to figure this information out?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913425/getting-all-contacts-timestamp-wise

Comment: You want to achieve the said thing programatically, as a developer or just as a Android phone user? I am unable to make it out reading your question!!